# Query on multiple collections at once (mongodb)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm not pretty sure could I do this. My application(buy and sell) have around five to ten categories `eg: vehicles, real estate, and cloths` I thought of creating separate MongoDB collections for each category because each of the categories contains with different fields `eg: vehicle[km, body type, brand], cloths[size, color, gender]`, This would be very easy to manage and scale.

Now can I able to send one query to those multiple collections at once

1. sort new ads - sort all new ads from all multiple collections in order
2. text search on field `eg: title` on all collections

server: nodejs

Comment: In elasticsearch you can use multi search api(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html)

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB 4.2 introduces [wildcard indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-wildcard/) specifically for this use case.